# Get div to shrink with image inside of it

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've got a div with only an image inside of it. The image takes up the whole space in the div normally and both the div and the image have the same height. Except when the window is shrinked, the image adjusts its size so it is responsive but the div maintains the same height. **How can I get the div to always have the same size as the image inside of it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position relative to achieve what you want:

**CSS**

```
#ProductPhoto {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 364px;

}
.photo {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-scale="1.7" class="product-single__photos tile col-md-8" id="ProductPhoto">       
            <img class="photo" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1698/6183/products/DSC_0345_123483_large.jpg?v=1486835408" alt="Another Skirt" id="ProductPhotoImg">
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpup1yz2/1/)**

Comment: I need the photo to be absolutely positioned for another effect that I have.

Comment: To expand the parent div you should have the child relative too.

Answer (score 1):

The div around image should have a property `display: inline-block` WITHOUT width set to 100%.

And why do you use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

on that image?

You also don't need `height: 100%;` on `#ProductPhoto`, because it will have the height of it's content anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do it with js ?
Take the pic height:

```
var pic_height = $('.photo').outerHeight();
```

Than give your pic container div the height of the pic:

```
$('#ProductPhoto').height(pic_height);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Height 100% will not work because div height is always dependent on its content, try to use

```
height: auto
```

instead of height: 100%